# document.querySelector vs Polymer.dom(this.$).querySelector

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

For below given code, does the `document.querySelector('createButton')` and `Polymer.dom(this.$).querySelector('createButton')` should return the same element?

If so, which one is best practice? Isn't it on first case we are search on whole dom tree(i mean including the host/root)? and on second one we are searching on just within this element's dom tree?

Should these both work at any point? Because I believe I have experienced a situation it the second case just works just inside `ready` (i mean when web component ready event is fired).

```html
<dom-module id="bortini-tv-create">
    <template>
        <form>
            <paper-input label="Name" value="{{tv.name}}"></paper-input>
            <paper-input label="Logo" value="{{tv.logo}}"></paper-input>
            <paper-input label="Address" value="{{tv.address}}"></paper-input>
            <paper-input label="Web site" value="{{tv.webSite}}"></paper-input>
            <paper-input label="Registration number" value="{{tv.regNumber}}"></paper-input>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <paper-button id="createButton" raised on-tap="handleTvCreate">
                <iron-icon icon="redeem"></iron-icon>
                Add
            </paper-button>
            <paper-button id="cancelButton" raised on-tap="handleCancelTvCreate">
                <iron-icon icon="cancel"></iron-icon>
                Cancel
            </paper-button>
        </form>

        <iron-ajax
                id="ironAjax"
                url="/api/tv"
                content-type="application/json"
                handle-as="json"
                method="POST">
        </iron-ajax>

        <paper-toast id="toast"
                     duration="3000"
                     text="TV {{tv.name}} has been created">
        </paper-toast>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 6):

As you say `document.querySelector('#createButton')` would search the whole document, and `Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('#createButton')` within `this` element's local DOM.

Note, you can also use `this.$$(selector)` for [locating dynamically-created nodes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding) in your element’s local DOM.

All of the above would work within an polymer element definition. I don't think any webcomponents `ready` event is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. I am facing a problem, when I do _italic_ this.$.createButton _italic_ or _italic_ document.querySelector('#createButton') _italic_ from "ready" it finds the button, but from iron-ajax event handling methods it does not find the element. I tried to debug, and most probably inside iron-ajax event handling methods the _italic_ this _italic_ is pointing to iron-ajax dom tree. any opinion?

Comment: @Jahid, can you provide some example code for those cases?

Comment: I have created a separate issue for that today. Here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865384/cant-find-element-on-iron-ajax-event-methods

Comment: @JahidShohel did my answer cover your original question? If so, could you accept it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry was busy with other stuffs this week. Will check soon and act accordingly.