# Can't find element on iron ajax event methods

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

For below given code `this.$.createButton` or `document.querySelector('createButton')` works inside the `ready` method. But same code fails inside `handleRequestSent` or `handleResponseReceived`. The error message I get is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createButton' of undefined

I tried to debug, it appears that inside `handleRequestSent` and `handleResponseReceived` the `this` actually pointing to iron-ajax, but not the element dom root.  Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

```html
<dom-module id="bortini-tv-create">
    <template>
        <form>
            <paper-input label="Name" value="{{tv.name}}"></paper-input>
            <paper-input label="Logo" value="{{tv.logo}}"></paper-input>
            <paper-input label="Address" value="{{tv.address}}"></paper-input>
            <paper-input label="Web site" value="{{tv.webSite}}"></paper-input>
            <paper-input label="Registration number" value="{{tv.regNumber}}"></paper-input>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <paper-button id="createButton" raised on-tap="handleTvCreate">
                <iron-icon icon="redeem"></iron-icon>
                Add
            </paper-button>
            <paper-button id="cancelButton" raised on-tap="handleCancelTvCreate">
                <iron-icon icon="cancel"></iron-icon>
                Cancel
            </paper-button>
        </form>

        <iron-ajax
                id="ironAjax"
                url="/api/tv"
                content-type="application/json"
                handle-as="json"
                method="POST">
        </iron-ajax>

        <paper-toast id="toast"
                     duration="3000"
                     text="TV {{tv.name}} has been created">
        </paper-toast>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>

    function initModel() {
        return {"name": "", "logo": "", "address": "", "webSite": "", "regNumber": ""};
    }


    Polymer({
        is: "bortini-tv-create",
        properties: {
            tv: {
                type: Object,
                value: initModel(),
                notify: true
            }
        },
        ready: function() {
            this.$.ironAjax.addEventListener('error', this.handleError);
            this.$.ironAjax.addEventListener('request', this.handleRequestSent);
            this.$.ironAjax.addEventListener('response', this.handleResponseReceived);
        },
        handleTvCreate: function (event) {
            var ironAjax=document.querySelector("#ironAjax");
            ironAjax.body = JSON.stringify(this.tv);
            ironAjax.generateRequest();
        },
        handleCancelTvCreate: function (event) {
            MoreRouting.navigateTo('tv-list');
        },
        handleError: function(event) {
            this.$.createButton.disabled=false;
            this.$.cancelButton.disabled=false;

            var request=event.detail.request;
            var error=event.detail.error;
            var toast=document.querySelector("#toast");
            toast.text="Error: "+error;
            toast.show();
        },
        handleRequestSent: function (request) {
            console.log("boooooo");
            this.$.createButton.disabled=true;
            this.$.cancelButton.disabled=true;

        },
        handleResponseReceived: function (response) {
            document.querySelector('createButton').disabled=false;
            document.querySelector('cancelButton').disabled=false;

            console.log("Received response: " + JSON.stringify(response.detail.response));
            document.querySelector('#toast').show();
            MoreRouting.navigateTo('tv-list');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set your event handlers imperatively the scope (i.e `this`) the handler is called with, isn't your element instance.

Two ways to solve this:

1. Bind the event handler to your element instance:

   `this.$.ironAjax.addEventListener('error', this.handleError.bind(this));`

   This will make sure that `this` inside of the event handler is actually the `this` you want.
2. Define the event handlers declaratively, then Polymer will take care of the proper binding:

   `<iron-ajax ... on-error="handleError" ...></iron-ajax>`

Answer (score 0):

this is because the responseHandler method is fired from an 
iron-request-element inside. So the this-context moves to the iron-ajax element. If you want to return to your "original" firing element from there, simply use the **this.parentElement** try something like this:

```
[...]
handleResponseReceived: function( request ) 
{
  var that = this.parentElement;
  that.$.createButton.disabled=true;
}
```

This should do the trick. Sorry for answering that late. ;)